# Finding a record with has many relationship and other params Ruby on Rails MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, pets and owners

```
class Owner < ApiModel

has_and_belongs_to_many :pets
```

and

```
class Pets < ApiModel

has_and_belongs_to_many :owners
```

So the example is three `Owners`, Frank, Mary, Hillary, who live together and own three `pets` (doggy, kitty, and fishy)

```
Owner1 = {name: "Mary", gender: "female", hair_color: "blue", pets: [pet1, pet2, pet3]} 
Owner2 = {name: "Hilary", gender: "female", hair_color: "green", pets: [pet1, pet2]} 
Owner3 = {name: "Frank", gender: "male", hair_color: "red", pets: [pet3]}
pet1 = {name: "doggy", gender: "female", animal: "dog"}
pet2 = {name: "kitty", gender: "male", animal: "cat"}
pet3 = {name: "fishy", gender: "male", animal: "fish"}
```

My goal is to return Owner 1 given that I know she owns pet3 and that she is female.
I thought I could do something like this:

```
found_pet = Pet.find_by(animal: "fish") # will correctly only return the pet3 record
owner = Owner.where(hair_color: "blue").includes(pet: found_pet)
```

But I keep getting an error `(Object doesn't support #inspect)` when trying to find owner.

Is this maybe possible with using `.join` ?

Rails version 6.0.4.7

Ruby version ruby 3.1.1p18

**UPDATE** (Answered in Comments)

Christos-Angelos Vasilopoulos had a good response for my original question but I had a follow up.

So what if I want to find where the owner own two pets:

```
found_pet1 = Pet.find_by(animal: "dog")
found_pet2 = Pet.find_by(animal: "cat") 
owner = Owner.where(hair_color: "blue").includes(pet: found_pet1).includes(pet: found_pet2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to use the association. Executing `pet_record.owners` returns all the pet owners. Then you need a query to return the right results.

Use `find_by` to get the first matching record for your query

```
found_pet.owners.find_by(hair_color: "blue")
```

Use `where` to get all the matching records for your query

```
found_pet.owners.where(hair_color: "blue")
```

PS: In your question your state that you need to return Owner1 as it is female, then I would suggest doing the following.

```
found_pet.owners.find_by(gender: "female")
found_pet.owners.where(gender: "female")
```

Comment: So what if i want to find where the owner own two pets:

found_pet1 = Pet.find_by(animal: "dog")
found_pet2 = Pet.find_by(animal: "cat")
owner = Owner.where(hair_color: "blue").includes(pet: found_pet1).includes(pet: found_pet2)

Comment: `found_pet1.owners.and(found_pet2.owners)` will return a collection of the owners for both of them.

Comment: undefined method `and' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy i get this error with the most recent solution. i am still trouble shooting

Comment: looks like the was `merge` not `and`

Comment: Thank you so much Christos-Angelos Vasilopoulos !

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be merge yes.